# Why isn't my Image displaying in the UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get an if statement which, if the selected button corresponded to the first image view, set it to the first image, else set it to the second image view... But, once I select the image from the `image picker`, it just ignores it and moves on like if nothing happened.
Here is my code:
(it down under the image picker controller func...)

```
class UploadSubPostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var previewStep: UIImageView!
}

class UploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var postscollectionview: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectStepsBtn: UIButton!

    var picker = UIImagePickerController()
    var isThumbnailImage = true
    var subpostsArray = [UIImage]()
    var subposts = [SubPost]()
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavigationBarItems()
        picker.delegate = self
    }

    func setupNavigationBarItems() {
        navigationItem.title = "Upload"
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

            let path = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
            let cell = self.postscollectionview.cellForItem(at: path) as? UploadSubPostCell

            if isThumbnailImage{
                previewImage.image = image
            } else {
                cell?.previewStep.image = image
            }
            selectBtn.isHidden = false
            selectStepsBtn.isHidden = false
            postBtn.isHidden = false
            if isThumbnailImage == false {
                subpostsArray.append(image)
                subposts.count + 1
                print("Appended image to array:", subpostsArray)
            }
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func selectStepPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        isThumbnailImage = false

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func selectPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        isThumbnailImage = true

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addNewPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }


    @IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://mobile-d9fcd.appspot.com")

        let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
        let imageRef = storage.child("posts").child(uid).child("\(key).jpg")
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.previewImage.image!, 0.6)

        let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                return
            }
                imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if let url = url {
                        let feed = ["userID" : uid,
                                    "pathToImage" : url.absoluteString,
                                    "likes" : 0,
                                    "author" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName!,
                                    "postID" : key] as [String : Any]

                        let postFeed = ["\(key)" : feed]

                        ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(postFeed)
                        AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                        self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    })
                }
            uploadTask.resume()
        }
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.posts.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

            cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
            cell.authorLabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].author
            cell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
            cell.postID = self.posts[indexPath.row].postID
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, you should save the **image** with the `dataSource`, if you know what `cell` the **image** goes into, use `tableView.reloadRows(at indexPaths:)` to reload the cell. Add the **image** to `cell.previewStep.image` in `cellForRowAt()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using swift version 4.2 and above, you should be replacing:

```swift
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
```

by:

```swift
if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
```